# Why are the wrapper Integer value and actual int value displayed differently in variables viewer (in Netbeans debug mode)?

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans

I learnt to use debug mode in NetBeans few days ago. One day, I was debugging a project when I saw the wrapper Integer has a value of 4 while the actual int value is 5.
Here is a variables debugger snippet:

[snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFX2u.png)

Why are they different? I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.2.

**[UPDATE]**

I created a minimal reproducible example:

```
 Integer i = 3;
 i+= 1;
```

and turn out, the int value was updated after the 2nd line while the Integer value stayed the same. I printed it out and it's 4 (the correct value). But why isn't the Integer in variable viewer updated?

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Because the unary plus (+=) operators do not apply to Integer objects, the compiler performs auto unboxing to perform the required operation. during your debugging process autoboxing has not taken place yet.

```
 Integer i = 3;
  i+= 1;

  System.out.println("Value of i = " + i + "  Data Type "+ i.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

the code snippet presented above will give you the following output

```
Value of i = 4,  Data Type: Integer
```

For more information, you can read the documentation

[Autoboxing and Unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)